# Is 1 hour feasible for a layover in Manila for an international flight?

Tags: international-travel, airports, layovers, short-connections, manila

Due to a flight change from Cebu Pacific I now have a 1 hour layover in Manila, no baggage, and the flights are on two seperate tickets.

Both flights are in terminal 3, I am flying on Cebu Pacific from Melbourne to Manila, and Air Asia from Manila to Osaka.

Is it feasible to have a one hour layover in Manila in this case or should I change the flight?

Comment: Standard question: Is that a single ticket or two separate tickets ?

Comment: This is two separate tickets.

Comment: @Yuki With two separate tickets, you are taking a great risk.  If everything goes well, you could make it but one small problem would be enough to cause you to miss your connection.

Comment: Even without baggage you have to allow time to deplane and get to the Air Asia departure gate before it closes (maybe passing through security on the way). If I were you I’d change the flight to an earlier inbound.